# Using const_cast to add const-ness - bad idea?

Tags: c++, pointers, const-cast

as we all know the usage of const_cast to remove the const-ness of a pointer should be avoided.

But how is it about the other way around?

For my use case I have a function that copies data (bytes) from a non-const source buffer.
I thought a good design decision would be to declare the parameter according to that source buffer fully const.

```
void copyfunction(const char* const data) { ... }
```

For a function call like below this would lead to a pointer-type error 'const char* const <-> char*'.

```
void main() {
    char sourcebuffer[] = {0x00};

    copyfunction(sourcebuffer);
}
```

Sure, now I could simply declare the `sourcebuffer` as const but in my case I don't have access to that variable because it's from a different code location (external library).

```
void main() {
    char sourcebuffer[] = {0x00};

    copyfunction(const_cast<const char* const>(sourcebuffer));
}
```

However the code beyond would work but is it good style (according to my use case)?

I thought declaring the parameter of the `copyfunction` as const assures the user of not modifying (read-only) the pointer or the location of the source buffer itself.
So in this case the const_cast would only be a necessary evil to enable to function call and not willfully remove the const-ness of a pointer...

Greets

Comment: In that use case http://ideone.com/BcI7Uq it compiles (once you make `main` return `int`).

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly cast it? The `const`ness will be [applied for you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02c6a2554453c4f6). And return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`.

Comment: It is unnecessary.  A non-const variable can be implicitly casted to const.

Comment: Aha! Very helpful! Sorry didn't know that for sure yet... So it make sense that you can only find code snipets of const_cast where it is used to remove const-ness.
Thanks!

Comment: @SteveMurdoc there are situations where `const_cast` adds `const`ness, but they are dangerous things to do: `int**` to `int const**` for example.  See here: http://ideone.com/tcByRQ

Answer (score 6):

You should not use `const_cast` to add `const`, because:

1. it's unnecessary. `T*` converts implicitly to `const T*`. Your question states that `char sourcebuffer[] = {0x00}; copyfunction(sourcebuffer);` is an error, but that's not true.
2. it's potentially (albeit unlikely) harmful. It can remove `volatile` from the pointer type, which is not the intention here and would result in undefined behavior if `sourcebuffer` were declared as `volatile sourcebuffer[]`.

Comment: Hi, what about add const-ness to call const class function? http://rextester.com/EFGPC9868

Answer (score 5):

You should not use `const_cast` to add `const` because

1. In the cases where the operation is safe, it is almost always not required.  `int*` turns into a `const int*` implicitly.
2. It can do something you don't want it to do.  It can strip `volatile`, or make you miss the fact that `const` was added somewhere else in your variables and your `const_cast` now silently strips them.
3. In the cases where it is required to add `const`, its use is dangerous in hard to reason about ways.

There are cases where you need to call `const_cast` in order to add `const` that will not happen implicitly.

```
void assign_ptr( int const*& lhs, int const* rhs ) { lhs = rhs; }
int const foo = 7;
int* bar = nullptr;
assign_ptr( const_cast<int const*&>(bar), &foo );
*bar = 2; // undefined behavior!
std::cout << foo << "@" << &foo << "\n"; // will print probably 7@something
std::cout << *bar << "@" << bar << "\n"; // will print probably 2@same address as above!
```

the above call to `assign_ptr` only adds `const`, but it will not happen implicitly.

A side effect of it is that modification of `*bar` is undefined behavior, as it modifies a variable declared `const` (it makes `bar`, a `int*`, point at `foo` a `const int`).

So while `const_cast` is required to make the `assign_ptr` call compile, *it is because it was unsafe*.  The `const_cast` doesn't make it safer, it just hides the error.

This is a specific case of the rectangle-square problem.  Squares are not Rectangles, because if you change the width of a Square its height also changes, and this does not happen when you modify a Rectangle.  Similarly, `int**` are not `int const**`.  (Note that immutable Squares are a kind of immutable Rectangle; it is the mutation that causes the issue.  In the case of pointers, a `int*const*` is a `int const*const*`: the mutability of the "higher level" pointers causes the problem.)

Comment: Pretty sure I already knew that rectangles are not squares. (Well, not all rectangles, anyway.) Less obvious, I think, is that Squares are not Rectangles...

Comment: @Nemo Ya, PEBKAC bug.  Fixed.

Comment: @Yakk  boost::optional<ptree const&> = get_child_optional(PATH); fails for the same reason in my code, as far as I can make out. I'm trying to state my intent of not modifying the ptree in my code. What's the right approach? Since the problem is probably with me, I'd like to change my thinking. 
On an aside, why is int * const* == int const * const *? This isn't something I've encountered before.