# c++ function name ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

My class has two functions with the same name and the following signature:

```
Mat<T, rows, cols> & transpose()
{   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < cols; ++j) {
            std::swap(at(i, j), at(j, i));
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

This method does an inplace transpose of the matrix. Now, I have another function which leaves the original matrix unchanged and does the transpose in a new matrix. The signature is:

```
Mat<T, cols, rows> transpose() const
```

Note that the columns and rows are swapped.

Now, I call it as:

```
Mat<int, 3, 4> d;
// Fill this matrix
Mat<int, 4, 3> e = d.transpose();
```

This still tries to call the first method. If I rename the second method to `transpose2` and call that, it is fine. Is there a way to make these two functions inambiguous?

Comment: Why don't you just call it `transposed`?

Comment: Declare `d` a `const`: `Mat<int, 3, 4> const d;`

Comment: Back then when I was reinventing the wheel to learn C++ (like you're doing apparently), I made one of them static and the other a method; or alternatively, I called one `getTranspose()` and the other `transpose()`.

Comment: @LogicStuff Sure I can do that but want to know what I am doing wrong...

Comment: @Luca What you're doing wrong: You can't overload with return value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I make it const than I cannot fill the matrix...or call any non-const methods.

Comment: @Luca There is no reason the `const` version should be preferred. Nor there is a way, which does not include the instance being `const` or casted to a `const`, or casting a member function pointer to the right overload.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I will just rename and get it done with!

Comment: *"This method does an inplace transpose"* - so I would call it `inplace_transpose`. :-)  The problem is two functions doing different things, but with the same name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) doesn't depend on the return value, it's determined by that which function whose parameters match the arguments most closely. You have to make the object being called on to be `const`, to make the `const` member function overload to be called. e.g.

```
Mat<int, 4, 3> e = const_cast<const Mat<int, 3, 4>&>(d).transpose();
```

Comment: @LogicStuff Yes. But shouldn't `const_cast` be more apporpriate here? Because it's relevant to `const`.

Comment: It's discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956757/using-const-cast-to-add-const-ness-bad-idea). It's up to the programmer, however. Some might be used to seeing `const_cast` only for removing cv-qualifiers, some not.

Comment: @LogicStuff I can understand that. Honestly I'm not sure myself either.

Answer (score 4):

You can't overload function by return type.Discussed in below thread

[Is it possible to have different return types for a overloaded method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807840/is-it-possible-to-have-different-return-types-for-a-overloaded-method)

In your case, you have overloded on the basis of "const". So second function will be called if you declare d as const otherwise the first version will be called.